# Rest architecture data relations

Tags: rest, architecture

I am planning the rest architecture of my current project and I want to know which architecture is better. My data consists of users, topics and posts.

So if my usecase requires to get all posts for a specific topic, how should I design it?

I know two approaches:

1. `http://restip/api/topics/:id/posts`
2. `http://restip/api/posts/?topicId`

So which one is recommended and are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The better way is the first, this link explain all the conventions (Base on ruby on rails conventions).

http://microformats.org/wiki/rest/urls

Is more easy to read a topic with the id have posts.

Answer (score 0):

That's really just a matter of taste. Just be consistant everywhere in your API.

In my opinion though, your second approach is good. It is better to keep it simple by preferring "shallow" URLs (with fewer levels) when possible :

```
/topics/:topicId
/posts/:postId
/posts/?topic=:topicId
```

You can add fancy URL rewrite rules later, if needed, so that for example:

`/topic/:topicId/posts` maps to `/posts/?topic=:topicId`